# Use Microsoft OAuth to authenticate our own operations

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

We have built a React web application that authenticates users with Microsoft via OAuth ( `@azure/msal-browser` package). Users are redirected to Microsoft auth page during signin, and then redirected back to our site once authentication has completed successfully. This is all working as expected.

However, we are in a position where we wish to add a custom PIN mechanism to protect some of our workflows. PINs will be encrypted/salted and stored in our own API, along with the existing mapping between Microsoft/Azure users and our own user state/records. In order for users to change/reset their PIN, we want to force them to reauthenticate with Microsoft *before* changing their PIN. I have not dealt with OAuth2 in a while, and am not entirely certain how this might be possible (since current auth workflow does not involve our server at all).

Ideally, users would navigate to the "Reset PIN" page and initiate the workflow. If possible, authentication would be handled through a pop-up (so as to not lose page state), which *I think* is possible as per [documentation](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/initialization.md#popup-apis)? If this is not possible, even a redirect to the same page with a specific query parameter (to indicate post-authentication) could work. The user would then be able to change/confirm their new PIN. At this point, a request would be sent to our API, including both the PIN **and** *something* from Microsoft that would allow our server to validate that the user did indeed just re-authenticate (proving they can change the PIN).

The primary sticking point is that our API **must** be able to verify that the user has just re-authenticated with Microsoft! One way to think about it would be that *if* a user gained temporary access to an unlocked authenticated workstation, they should not be able to perform restricted actions (as they do not know the PIN), nor be able to change the PIN (as they do not know the user's credentials). *Yes, yes, I know physical access is effectively a compromise to any security, but this is a higher-level requirement...*

I am guessing this workflow is possible, but am not certain *how* it might be possible. Would we use a different authentication workflow for this particular use case? Any pointers on a workflow we could investigate or use for this?

Answer (score 0):

I can give you some info about how this should work. This type of flow can require a high level of extensibility in the authorization server though.

**CLIENT REDIRECT**

The client can send the OpenID Connect [acr_values](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest) parameter, indicating the assurance levels it requires. In your case you would send two values.

**CUSTOM AUTHENTICATION FACTOR**

The user will perform standard authentication first, eg passwords. Then you would implement a custom second factor that uses the user identity and some custom logic to call your custom API.

**ACCESS TOKENS**

After authentication has completed, the authorization server will issue access tokens to the client. High privilege claims should only be included when strong authentication has been used. Some kind of scripting would be used here, that can read authentication result attributes.

**API AUTHORIZATION**

APIs should receive short lived access tokens. If it contains the high privilege claim, you know that your PIN requirements have been met.

**CAN YOU SIMPLIFY?**

It feels suspect to do your own PIN management. Can you outsource this, eg use a second factor of time based one time password (TOTP) instead? Mobile platforms such as the Google authenticator app provide tested solutions.